# Do search engines support HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https

I was reading "Cryptography and Network Security" by William Stallings and I came across a paragraph (Chapter 16.4) explaining HTTPS. Among some other stuff, it said that

> search engines do not support HTTPS

How is this true since the major search engines that I tried (Google, Yahoo, Bing) have a https:// URL before doing the search (index) and after (results page). I don't know how to check if the statement in the book is true or not.

One idea that came to mind is that those search engines just display everything (index, result page) over a HTTPS but submit the keyword searches over a non-secure HTTP. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fifth edition of the book was released in 2011 when most search engines did not support HTTPS [(Google added HTTPS support to its search in 2010)](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/search-more-securely-with-encrypted.html).

The sixth edition of this book (2013) has the following statement:

> "For example, some search engines do not support HTTPS. Google
>   provides HTTPS as an option: https://google.com."

replacing this text in the fifth edition that you are referring to:

> "For example, search engines do not support HTTPS."

This may have been accurate at that time but is now outdated and will probably be corrected in the next edition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's great that the book has already fixed it in it's new edition. It's one of the problems with books dealing with these kind of technologies that are always evolving